# Using OpenGl wrappers for java in xcode

Tags: java, xcode, opengl, jogl

I've been using opengl with c++ for quite some time now, and I'm hoping to expand to the android/mac-app market by learning to use opengl with java. I'd like to be able to do this in xcode because it packages the app so neatly, but I'm mostly new to xcode and it's quite foreign to me. I've been trying to figure out how to get it to work with jogl, to no success - and I have no idea where to go! The internet is completely void of help.
Does anyone have thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode is very painful for developing java. I would discourage it. There are plenty of very decent java editors that offer the same sort of debugging and packaging. Xcode will not allow you to build for Android without serious modifications and hacks.

Xcode is very good for developing Objective-C which is what you should focus on if you are planning on developing for iOS/Mac.

Apple has a lot of tutorials on using OpenGL (ES) but they are all based on Obj-C.

I would suggest finding a good IDE for Java such as Eclipse. Downloading the Android SDK will get you a version of Eclipse specifically for developing for Android. Then following a java tutorial such as:

http://www.land-of-kain.de/docs/jogl/

Google also offers tutorials on OpenGL ES for Android with their api:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html

In summary, my experience in trying to get Xcode to play nice with Java will result in frustration. Learning eclipse is very valuable as it is actually quite a ubiquitous editor.

Comment: Thanks! I'll admit I'm a bit disappointed, but such is life. Have a nice day!